# Controlling the amount of space in justify-content: space-between

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I was wondering how to justify how much space is allowed in `justify-content: space-between` for flexbox.

Currently, my items are spaced but they have way too much space between them I want just a little space between them so they can settle somewhere in the middle in a row.

The snippet below will hopefully clarify what I'm struggling with.

Let me know if you need me to clarify further. Thanks!

```css
#qwrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row {
  flex: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}
#lighticon {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #qwrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #qwrapper {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .row {}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
  #qwrapper {
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 10px;
  }
  #lighticon {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="qwrapper">

  <h3 id="michelle" class="row">"She always thinks of her clients."
<br>
   
</h3>

  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-icon-social-media/512/099310-feedburner-logo.png" class="row" alt="" id="lighticon" />

  <h3 id="jerry" class="row">"Very smart, creative person, problem solver."
<br>


</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Try justify-content: space around; with margin-left for flex items.

Comment: Maybe use `justify-content: center;` on the flex parent and use `margin: 0 50px;` on the `img`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `justify-content` property uses the available space on the line to position flex items.

With `justify-content: space-between`, all available space is placed between the first and last items, pushing both items to opposite edges of the container.

*You wrote:*

> I was wondering how to justify how much space is allowed in `justify-content: space-between` for flexbox.

With `space-between` in row-direction, you would have to control the width of the flex container. So if you want there to be less space between flex items, then you would need to shorten the width of the container.

Or you could use `justify-content: space-around`.

However, these solutions are suboptimal.

The right way to go about this would be to use margins.

*You wrote:*

> Currently, my items are spaced but they have way too much space between them I want just a little space between them so they can settle somewhere in the middle in a row.

Use `justify-content: center` then use margins to space them apart.

Answer (score 4):

My solution was :

- put dummy empty divs in between with a max-height specified
- change space-between to flex-start
- set the content blocks to nogrow
- set the dummy divs to grow

Then the spaces grow up to a max specified.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I simply made a <div style="width: 40px; height: 0px"> </div> which gives me spacing control between items when they're horizontal. When flex-wrap gets triggered, the dummy spacer does nothing because it's 0px height, or I could set some height to it too. Works fine, nothing else needed.

Comment: After I wrote this I also discovered the effect of margin-left or margin-right: auto for flex items. Its a supported way to anchor things. Depends on the situation of course but can be a super easy solution to get something to just move!

Comment: This probably won't work on responsive design.

Answer (score 2):

I find myself adding right margin to all the boxes (in this case three)

```
.three {
    margin-right: 2%
}
```

and then getting rid of it so the last box aligns right

```
.three:nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 0%;
}
```

but every time I do this I think "there has to be a better way, something baked into flex-box...this works but it seems like a workaround?

Comment: Is this still the case we find ourselves in?

Answer (score 2):

The approach with using margins is not a universal solution if you want `space-between`, because it would set a margin on all the flex-elements, also on the first and last elements on a line or column. Using `:first-child` / `:last-child`/ `:nth-child()` selector doesn't help when `flex-wrap: wrap` is set, because you can never tell which elements will be first and last on a wrapped line or column.

A selector like `:wrapped` would be helpful, but sadly it doesn't exist.

So my conclusion is that when you really want to unleash the flexibility and responsiveness of the flexbox, you can't control the margins… Missed opportunity of the spec I'd say.